# How to reference local assemblies in roslyn analyzer tests?

Tags: c#, roslyn, roslyn-code-analysis

I´m creating a roslyn analyzer to check the usage of an attribute from my framework code.
Example:

**Framework.csproj**

```cs
public class ModuleAttribute : Attribute { }
```

**Framework.Analyzer.csproj**

```cs
[DiagnosticAnalyzer(LanguageNames.CSharp)]
public class IsModuleAPublicClassAnalyzer : DiagnosticAnalyzer
{ ... }
```

**Framework.Analyzer.Test.csproj**

```cs
[Fact]
public async Task MyTestMethod()
{
    string test = @"
using Framework;

namespace MyNamespace;

[Module]
public class MyConcreteModule
{
}
";

    DiagnosticResult expected = VerifyCs
        .Diagnostic(AsyncPropertySetterAnalyzer.DiagnosticId)
        .WithLocation(line: 6, column: 0);

    await new CSharpAnalyzerTest<IsModuleAPublicClassAnalyzer, XUnitVerifier>
    {
        TestState =
        {
            Sources = { test  },
            ExpectedDiagnostics = { expected }
        }
    }
    .RunAsync();
}
```

How can I add a reference to `Framework.dll` in the test codesnippet?
All projects are in the same solution.

### Update 1

I noticed that it is possible to add additional `MetadataReference`s like this:
**Framework.Analyzer.Test.csproj**

```cs
[Fact]
public async Task MyTestMethod()
{
    string test = @"
using Framework;

namespace MyNamespace;

[Module]
public class MyConcreteModule
{
}
";

    DiagnosticResult expected = VerifyCs
        .Diagnostic(AsyncPropertySetterAnalyzer.DiagnosticId)
        .WithLocation(line: 6, column: 0);

    await new CSharpAnalyzerTest<IsModuleAPublicClassAnalyzer, XUnitVerifier>
    {
        TestState =
        {
            Sources = { test  },
            ExpectedDiagnostics = { expected },
            AdditionalReferences =
            {
                MetadataReference.CreateFromFile(typeof(ModuleAttribute).Assembly.Location)
            }
        }
    }
    .RunAsync();
}
```

Now I get that error:

```
error CS1705: Assembly 'Framework' with identity 'Framework, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=29fe1ef4929b04aa' uses 'System.Runtime, Version=7.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' which has a higher version than referenced assembly 'System.Runtime' with identity 'System.Runtime, Version=4.2.2.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'
```

`Framework.csproj` and `Framework.Analyzer.Test.cspoj` have
target framework `net7.0`
`Framework.Analyzer.csproj` is `netstandard2.0`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Solution

I solved it by adding `ReferenceAssemblies` like this:

```cs
[Fact]
public async Task MyTestMethod()
{
    string test = @"
using Framework;

namespace MyNamespace;

[Module]
public class MyConcreteModule
{
}
";

    DiagnosticResult expected = VerifyCs
        .Diagnostic(AsyncPropertySetterAnalyzer.DiagnosticId)
        .WithLocation(line: 6, column: 0);

    await new CSharpAnalyzerTest<IsModuleAPublicClassAnalyzer, XUnitVerifier>
    {
        TestState =
        {
            Sources = { test  },
            ExpectedDiagnostics = { expected },
            AdditionalReferences =
            {
                MetadataReference.CreateFromFile(typeof(ModuleAttribute).Assembly.Location)
            },
            // ReferenceAssemblies = ReferenceAssemblies.Net.Net60 // the default from Microsoft
            ReferenceAssemblies = Net.Net70 // custom because there is no net70 version in the provided Nuget yet.
        }
    }
    .RunAsync();
}
```

My custom net70 `ReferenceAssemblies`:

```cs
using Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Testing;
using System.Collections.Immutable;

namespace Framework.Analyzers.Test;

internal static class Net
{
    private static readonly Lazy<ReferenceAssemblies> _lazyNet70 = new(() =>
        new ReferenceAssemblies(
            "net7.0",
            new PackageIdentity(
                "Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref",
                "7.0.0-preview.5.22301.12"),
            Path.Combine("ref", "net7.0")));
    public static ReferenceAssemblies Net70 => _lazyNet70.Value;

    private static readonly Lazy<ReferenceAssemblies> _lazyNet70Windows = new(() =>
        Net70.AddPackages(
            ImmutableArray.Create(
                new PackageIdentity("Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App.Ref", "7.0.0-preview.5.22302.5"))));
    public static ReferenceAssemblies Net70Windows => _lazyNet70Windows.Value;
}
```

Comment: it can be now updated to "7.0.7" version and works perfectly fine, thanks! it's crazy how it's still  not available in the original class and now little docs on that is available

Answer (score 1):

Update for latest syntax:

```cs
var ut = new VerifyCS.Test
{
    TestState =
    {
        Sources = { test },
    },
    ExpectedDiagnostics = { VerifyCS.Diagnostic(MyAnalyzer.DiagnosticId) },
};

ut.TestState.AdditionalReferences.Add(typeof(IMyInterface).Assembly);
await ut.RunAsync();
```

Be sure to include a `ProjectReference` to the Project in your sln that contains your interface.

Answer (score 0):

Don't try that, it's not supported in a nice way in Analyzers currently. You need to reference / resolve the type / namespace / assembly names via strings.

You can get your attribute's Symbol (!) from the compilation. A Symbol is not the same as the actual Type. e.g.

```cs
public override void Initialize(AnalysisContext ac)
{
  ac.RegisterCompilationStartAction(start=> {
    // Avoid calling this often!
    // Can be null if the currently complied project
    // doesn't know about this type!
    var moduleAttribute = csa.Compilation.GetTypeByMetadataName("Framework.ModuleAttribute");

    // Analyze all the declared classes types in your solution
    start.RegisterSymbolAction(
      symbolKinds: new[] { SymbolKind.NamedType },
      action: ctx => {
        var currentType = ctx.Symbol as INamedTypeSymbol;

        // <check if currentType must have an [ModuleAttribute]>

        // if yes, then
        var attributes = currentType.GetAttributes();
        var hasModuleAttribute = attributes.Any(
          attr => attr.AttributeClass.Equals(moduleAttribute));

        // emit diagnostics if needed...
      });
  });
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But I think you misunderstood the question.
I was not asking about how to write the analyzer - that is more or less how you suggested.
The Question was about how to write the test. In my opinion, it must be possible to reference the 'Framework.dll'  in the test compilation...
In the meantime I noticed that it is possible to add the path to the assembly to the `AdditionalReferences` - but there I geht an Assembly missmatch error between System.Runtime.dll 7.0.0 & 4.2.0...